# Я хотел залить сайт на сервере heroku

Tags: git, heroku, git-commit

Я дошёл до 'git commit -am "make it better"' но она выдаёт ошибку 'On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean'

при 'git add .' ничего не происходит